# is there any one help me for the submit the application in to app store?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

When i upload my application into the app store i getting error like:

> application failed codesign verification. the signature was invalid,
>   or it was not signed with an iphone distrubution certificate
>
> icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app
>   wrapper:Icon.png

could you please any one help me for solve this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems. First you need to obtain a distribution certificate and create a distribution provisioning profile. You can create these things at the Apple Developer Portal, it will also explain how to do it there.

Member Center > Provisioning Portal > Distribution

The second issue is it's saying it can't find the icon for your app, have you made one? Is it named Icon.png?

Comment: yes i already create the distribution certificate and inside i Icon.png is included. i couldn't able to find  the problem

Comment: Did you create a distribution provisioning profile and drop it into Xcode? You need a profile for development AND distribution.

Comment: yes i done all the steps for submit the app but still showing the error

Comment: Thank you for your support 

please check my screenshots  below:

![enter image description here][1]


![enter image description here][2]


![enter image description here][3]


But still same error. i don


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa5Pj.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeD1.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/39eGw.jpg

Comment: The icon should be in the root directory as the warning message says.

Answer (score 0):

You've either used the wrong profile to sign your app with, or you don't have a distribution profile.

You can get them, and see the instructions on obtaining them on the iOS Provisioning profile on the Apple Developer site.

Once you've installed it, you need to correctly set your app's Build settings to use the correct profiles when building. Since you are uploading the Release build to the app store, make sure that you set the Distribution profile for that configuration, and that the scheme you are using to build the app for upload uses that configuration.

[image]

As for the second problem. You have placed values into the Info.plist about your icons, but they are not being found. Make sure you gave a graphic file named `Icon.png` (and `Icon@2x.png` to support retina displays) and that it is being copied to the top level of your application bundle rather than any subdirectories.

Comment: i changed but still i am getting same error

Comment: @ AbiZem

Thank you for your support 

please check my screenshots  below:![enter image description here][1]


![enter image description here][2]


![enter image description here][3]


But still same error. i don


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa5Pj.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeD1.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/39eGw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the (possibly when adding multiple icons and changing the file?) the item gets moved to `item 1-...`
Make sure your icon is listed as `item 0` in the `plist`

[image]